# How to simplify this Gradle command line?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am new to Gradle and have gotten a fairly sophisticated build working with it so far (runs tests, uses CodeNarc, generates API docs, generates a sources JAR, etc.). The command line for a "full build" (that is, to execute all the major tasks that the CI server should be running), I need to enter the following Gradle command at the shell:

```
gradle clean build check groovydoc sourcesJar createPom dist -Pversion=<version>
```

Where `<version>` is the version I want to build.

I would like to condense this and add an alias so that all of the above can be accomplished with something simple, like:

```
gradle full-build
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

---

### My `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'codenarc'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.3'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

groovydoc

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

task dist(type: Zip, dependsOn: build) {
    classifier = 'buildreport'

    from('build/test-results') {
        include '*.xml'
        into 'tests'
    }

    from('build/reports/codenarc') {
        into 'reports'
    }

    from('build/docs') {
        into 'api'
    }

    from(sourcesJar) {
        into 'source'
    }

    from('build/libs') {
        exclude '*-sources.jar'
        into 'bin'
    }
}

task createPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId "me"
            artifactId "myapp"
            version version
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/myapp-${version}.pom")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above build invocation, at least `check` and `sourcesJar` can be omitted already. (`build` depends on `check`, and `from(sourcesJar)` tells Gradle that `dist` depends on `sourcesJar`.) By adding further task dependencies (e.g. `build.dependsOn dist`), you can cut it down to `gradle clean build -Pversion=...`. `dist` should not depend on `build` but on the specific tasks that produce the artifacts that go into the zip (e.g. `groovydoc` and `createPom`).

Reducing `gradle clean build` to `gradle fullBuild` is more difficult, as Gradle doesn't currently have a first-class concept of "aliases", and adding `build.dependsOn(clean)` is usually not desirable. One way out is to implement your own aliasing mechanism by manipulating `gradle.startParameter.taskNames`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Niederwieser (+1) - and sorry it took so long to circle back to this. Two followup questions: (1) You say to reduce the invocation to `gradle clean build -Pversion=...` I need to do a `build.dependsOn dist`. Where should I put this code? I tried adding it in various locations and it always produces a failed build. And (2) Did you by any chance forget about `createPom`? Is there a way to get `gradle clean build` also invoking `createPom`? If so, how? Thanks again!

Comment: ad 1. e.g. `task dist(...) { ... }; build.dependsOn dist`. ad 2. Reread my answer ("dist should not depend on build but ...").